# ! Missing $ inserted R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I had running scripts in R Markdown to produce .pdf documents that included figures in the outputs. I have run them for a while with no issues.

After updating to `RStudio 1.4`, I am getting the following error when trying to create the .pdf output using Rmarkdown:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.225 ...files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-6-1.pdf}
```

As suggested in https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging, I have followed the steps updating my R packages and tinytex, but the issue persist.

Any ideas what is generating this issue and if it is related to the  update to RStudio 1.4?

Thanks

Comment: needs a reproducible example - a short piece of markdown that replicates the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You have latex that isn't properly closed. This generates the same error.
`A donut will cost you $5 \int with tax.`

If your intention was to make latex, you gotta close the expression with another `$`. Or if it wasn't, you gotta escape the backslash with another backslash. `\\int`.